# Ranking numbers' loop in swift

Tags: ios, swift, loops, ranking

I am trying to make a ranking in a `tableView` in Swift but I can't set the numbers of each cell. I am trying to make a `for loop` to start with the number 1 and increment it as long as I have cells in my `tableView`.

I've tried this :

```
@IBOutlet weak var rank: UILabel!

for var i = 1; i <= numberOfRows; i += 1 {
        myCell.name.text = "i"
    }
```

A `Use of unresolved identifier numberOfRows` error appears. I've tried to replace it by `myCell.count` or other `elements.count` but it doesn't work either.

I think it's pretty easy to do but I'm new to Swift and I don't manage to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full code (the rank's IBOutlet is on another page) :

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class VC0: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let LocationManager = CLLocationManager()

var arrDataArticles: NSMutableArray!

@IBOutlet weak var myCity: UINavigationItem!

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

var images = UIImage(named: "avatar")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //CoreLocation
    self.LocationManager.delegate = self
    self.LocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.LocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.LocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    //Data
    self.getAllArticles()
}

//Location
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {
        (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error")
        }

        if let pm = placemarks?.first {
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        }
        else {
            print("Error : data error")
        }

    })
}

func displayLocationInfo (placemark: CLPlacemark) {

    self.LocationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    print(placemark.subThoroughfare)
    print(placemark.thoroughfare)
    print(placemark.locality)
    print(placemark.postalCode)
    print(placemark.subAdministrativeArea)
    print(placemark.administrativeArea)
    print(placemark.country)
    myCity.title = placemark.locality

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Error :" + error.localizedDescription)
}

//Data
func getAllArticles() {
    arrDataArticles = NSMutableArray()
    arrDataArticles = ModelBD.getInstance().getAllArticles()
    myTableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrDataArticles.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let myCell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CustomCell

    let article: ArticlesData = arrDataArticles.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! ArticlesData

    for var i = 1; i <= numberOfRows; i += 1 {
        myCell.rank.text = "i"
    }

    //myCell.rank.text = ranks[indexPath.row]
    myCell.photo.image = images

    //myCell.name.text = "i"
    myCell.city.text = article.districtArticle

    return myCell
}

}
```

Comment: @NDoc I just added the rest of the code.

Comment: @Khuong thanks for your suggestion, so you think I should create a count function instead of doing a loop?

Comment: do not want the for loop . Just you will enter in cellforindexpath myCell.rank.text = indexpath.row will display like a rank 0,1,2, upto array count.

Comment: @ThéoFleismaher Why are you using for loop to change value of rank label, also there is no variable `numberOfRows` thats why you are getting this error.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the answers, so I will delete the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any loop. Just use the `indexPath.row`. It's already in the order from 0 to `arrDataArticles.count - 1`

```
myCell.rank.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
```

For full context:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let myCell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CustomCell

    let article: ArticlesData = arrDataArticles.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! ArticlesData

    myCell.rank.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

    //myCell.rank.text = ranks[indexPath.row]
    myCell.photo.image = images

    //myCell.name.text = "i"
    myCell.city.text = article.districtArticle

    return myCell
}
```

Comment: I already tried this but it says "Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'String'.